# I want to learn driver developement so how to start in this?

Tags: driver, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I want to learn device driver development so how to start ? Any media for beginner or something ?

Comment: This is not really the kind of question SO is for.  You are better off doing a google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical reference is [Linux Device Drivers 3rd Edition](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) - although it's a few years old now, it's close enough to current kernels.

Quite a lot of stuff is not covered in here - particularly anything that's device or bus specific, or the way the kernel has been developing to support ARM SoC devices over the last few years.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go start learing Linux device driver under PC environment so as you can co-relate most of things you are familier with ,One approach is to go get linux source code and try to understand how kernel is being called and how single user space process is initiated from  kernel space .You can also follow this below given page would be helpful for you.

http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Reading_the_Linux_Kernel_Sources